# Javascript location

Tags: javascript, custom-masterpage

I am trying to create tabs using this code

http://jsfiddle.net/yZYtL/

I have implimented the HTML and CSS OK but the I am unsure where the Javascript should go?  I have an existing javascript in use for the masterpages etc but when I have pasted the script from the website into the current script the tabs don't work.  If I click on a tab, it doesn't load, any ideas?

Comment: Use developers tool bar for the browser and check if the latest script was loaded correctly.. Press Ctrl+F5 to refresh the browser cache

Answer (score 0):

Solved user error!  I didn't make the tabs as active.

Answer (score 0):

only add references such as Jquery, bootstrap... because not fire in onLoad, result message error: "$" is undefined, and have added Jquery to fiddle and work fine :)